# C# String do not replace tabulation char

Tags: c#

I have to replace some set of characters in string include tabulation, and the tab stays the same. Code I'm working with:

```
public class Characters
{
    IConfiguration _config;

    [FunctionName("Replace")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string correctName = null;
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
                correctName = ReplaceCharacters(requestBody);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogWarning(ex.Message);
        }

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody)
            ? "Pass a name in the request body to convert."
            : $"{correctName}";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }

    public Characters(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this._config = config;
    }

    public string ReplaceCharacters(string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace("%", "_");
        value = value.Replace("$", "_");
        value = value.Replace(";", "_");


        value = value.Replace("\t", "_");
        value = Regex.Replace(value, "[\x09]", "_");

        return value;
    }
}
```

Body HTTP POST request in Postman: M%e$s;a[tab]g

Response: M_e_s_a[tab]g

**edit:**
The postman and Visual studio uses 4 spaces instead tabulation, I've copied tab from notepad now it's working

This is not replacing NBSP now

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, "[\0xC2\0xA0]", "_");
```

I'm copying it from site:

> https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0

And paste in postman

It's interesting, because it's replacing other spaces like U+2002, U+2003, U+2007, and a bunch of other characters but not U+00A0.

I'm replacing it like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> c in dict)
{
    char a = (char)int.Parse(c.Key, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    char b = (char)int.Parse(c.Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b);

    name = name.Replace(a, b);
}
```

And in dictionary I have 00A0, 2002, 2003, 2007 as keys and _ as a value

Comment: I would log the string before and after to see what’s going on. It’s possible you’re actually sending an escape sequence of some kind instead of an actual tab character.

Comment: Are you sure the `requestBody` has a tab in it?  If you debug and inspect it what does it show?  can you copy and paste the exact string into the question?

Comment: I'm sure. I can't, because Stack Overflow doesn't allow use tab char in questions. :) [tab] it is actually tab character :)

Comment: I've logged the string before and after in function itself, and it's the same like the response

Comment: check the ASCII value of the character that you think is `<tab>`... if it's `<tab>` then it should be `9`

Comment: SO certainly does let you use tabs in questions, though it will look like a space because HTML treats whitespace the same. If you aren't able to paste it in I suspect it's not a tab character.

Comment: Do this: `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody))` then post the resulting string, this will give us a 100% byte-for-byte copy of the original string and we can see for ourselves what exactly is going on here.

Comment: I've done it as you said, now the message is: Messa ge, and response: TWVzc_EgZ_U_

Comment: Okey, when I copy &nbsp char from VS console then it replaces correctly: Array of bytes recieved: 77 194 160 194 160 101 194 160 115 32 97 32 103 32 101 32 for request: M  e s a g e  . 194 160 in UTF-8 is &nbsp, 32 is normal space. It looks like Postman converting &nbsp to normal space when its copied from the browser.